# Where i should put 2D array?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

I have to create class Matrix with matrix, where in private - 2d array for storing its elements, the number of rows and columns. In private i should create just array like this:

```
class Matrix{
    int row;
    int column;
    int mat[100][100]
}
```

Or in private part I should add a func and costructor, that will create matrix?

Comment: If you don't know the number of rows and columns at compile-time, why not use `std::vector` instead? Then set the sizes when you know the number of rows/dolumns.

Comment: the question is unclear. You want the member private then declare it private, it already is in your code. If you make the constructor private it will be difficult to create objects

Comment: Normally, it can be stored in a 1d array, like what MATLAB does. (column-first or row-first it is up to you)